# is there any way to find weitage of sentence with TF-IDF in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have one list

```
x=["hello there","hello world","my name is john"]
```

i am done with vectorization with TF-IDF

this is output of TF-idf

```
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  corpus = [
         "hello there","hello world","my name is john", ]
  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

  X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

  X.toarray()



array([[0.60534851, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
      0.79596054, 0.        ],
     [0.60534851, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
      0.        , 0.79596054],
     [0.        , 0.5       , 0.5       , 0.5       , 0.5       ,
      0.        , 0.        ]])
```

can we find weightage of every sentence (compare with all documents)??

if yes then How??

Comment: Can you share full code and explain what is the idea of TF-idf?

Comment: yea , Did it , take a look @Anteino

Comment: Ok hold on while I install those libraries and figure out how TF-idf works.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by weight of each sentence? Do you mean the added weight of all words in that sentence? Or do you want to find those whole sentences in another document?

Comment: @Anteino i want to do something like `Page ranking`  Like (sentence 1 has high probability like that )

Comment: Page ranking of webpage X is related to the amount of links directing to X from websites other than X. How does this relate to your example? Are you trying to find out which documents contain references to other documents?

Comment: @Anteino Are you trying to find out which documents contain references to other documents? YESSSSS  just consider(documents==sentence)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with TF-idf you can only calculate the weight of single words in a sentence (or document for that matter), meaning you cannot use it to calculate the weight of sentences within other sentences or documents.

However, from [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-process-textual-data-using-tf-idf-in-python-cd2bbc0a94a3/) page I learned how TF-idf works. You can "abuse" the functions they give by changing them to what you need specifically. Allow me to demonstrate:

```
import math

corpus = ["hello there", "hello world"]

file = open("your_document.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()

def computeTF(sentences, document):
    dict = {i: 0 for i in sentences}
    filelen = len(text.split(' ')) - 1

    for s in sentences:
        #   Since we're counting a whole sentence (containing >= 1 words) we need to count
        #   that whole sentence as a single word.
        sLength = len(s.split(' '))
        dict[s] = document.count(s)
        #   When you know the amount of occurences of the specific sentence s in the
        #   document, you can recalculate the amount of words in that document (considering
        #   s as a single word.
        filelen = filelen - dict[s] * (sLength - 1)

    for s in sentences:
        #   Since only after the previous we know the amount of words in the document, we
        #   need a separate loop to calculate the actual weights of each word.
        dict[s] = dict[s] / filelen

    return dict

def computeIDF(dict, sentences):
    idfDict = {s: dict[s] for s in sentences}
    N = len(dict)

    for s in sentences:
        if(idfDict[s] > 0):
            idfDict[s] = math.log10(N)
        else:
            idfDict[s] = 0

    return idfDict

dict = computeTF(corpus, text)
idfDict = computeIDF(dict, corpus)

for s in corpus:
    print("Sentence: {}, TF: {}, TF-idf: {}".format(s, dict[s], idfDict[s]))
```

This code example only looks at a single text file, but you can easily extend it to look at several text files.